# Calling a c# web form web service from Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I created a c# aspx.cs web form web service in visual studio which would return a string of Json result upon calling this:

```
string url = "http://crowd.sit.nyp.edu.sg/FRSIPad/GetFacilities.aspx?DepartmentID=" + departmentID
            + "&Block=" + block + "&Level=" + level + "&Name=" + name + "&DeviceID=&Hash=";
```

The web service is written in Json RESTful method.
I hosted the program on the IIS server. 
I read about calling the web service from Xamarin studio. I am doing this on the cross-platform and running on IOS. I have researched about HttpWebRequest and i am not sure if i am on the right track. Please advice how i can call this web service of mine and store it into a c# object in xamarin? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could do a basic search and would lot of tutotrials explaining how to do it. Here are a few - [Introduction to Web Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) , [Call a REST Web Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/), [Consuming Web Services using Xamarin](http://www.nullskull.com/a/10476774/consuming-web-services-using-xamarin.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

U can use these tutorials

1) https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

2)https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using RestSharp successfully in a Xamarin project.  It works great.

Check it out: http://restsharp.org/